Finding $B$ such that a section of the graph of $y=\cot\left(Bx-\frac\pi6\right)$ has asymptotes at $x=-10\pi/3$ and $x=2\pi/3$.
I got the below question on Mathacademy with the correct answer being $\frac{1}{4}$.

To solve similar questions before, I'd look at the graph for some known (x, y) pairs and solve using that value. For this question, for example, I know $cot(x)$ goes to $-\infty$ at $x = \pi$. So I do the following:
$$ B\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) - \frac{\pi}{6} = \pi $$
Solving this I get:
$$ B = \frac{7}{4} $$
But this is not the right answer. And I know it isn't because when I plot the function
$$ y = \cot\left(\frac{7x}{4} - \frac{\pi}{6}\right) $$
The graph is different. So my first question is, why does this method not work? When I try using $n\pi$ instead of $\pi$, the solution is:
$$ \frac{6n + 1}{4} $$
Which matches the given answer for $n = 0$. But $n$ cannot be zero.
Then, if I solve it using the method taught in the lesson, I first get the period of the function which is $4\pi$. So the solution is simply equate the period as:
$$ T = \frac{\pi}{B} $$
Putting $T = 4\pi$ again gives the right answer for $B$.
This gives the equation as:
$$ y = \cot\left(\frac{x}{4} - \frac{\pi}{6}\right) $$
The thing is, if I put the value $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ in this equation, I still get $\infty$ ant not $-\infty$ as per the graph. What gives? I feel like I'm missing something very obvious.
